# Wider body in a GitHub Pages site

Tags: html, github, markdown, jekyll, github-pages

My [GitHub Pages site](https://cubically.github.io) looks like this:

[image: pages site]

I don't like how thin the body is (it's padded with blank space on both sides, each making up 33% of the page). This is theme-independent, as it was happening before I activated my [current Jekyll theme](https://github.com/pages-themes/slate). I can't find any information on how to expand the part of the body that actually has content.

As is usual with Jekyll, I use Markdown for the webpages, so I can't manually edit any HTML to remove the whitespace.

How can I make the amount of blank space on the sides of the body smaller?

Comment: Right-click, "Inspect element". Poke around a little, and you'll find that the `.inner` class has a `max-width: 640px;` CSS rule. Remove/adjust that.

Comment: Googling "customize github theme" brings up https://help.github.com/articles/customizing-css-and-html-in-your-jekyll-theme/ as the very first result.

Answer (score 13):

Create a file `/docs/assets/style.scss` with this content at the top of the file:

```
---
---

@import "{{ site.theme }}";

.inner {
  max-width: 75%;
}
```

Change `75%` to the desired width of the body.

Found with help from [ceejayoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1902010/ceejayoz).

Comment: Looks like the file actually needs to be `/assets/css/style.scss` according to https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/adding-a-theme-to-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll